# Syntax error using try: except within a for loop to handle DivideZeroError

Tags: python, django, for-loop

Iterating across multiple dicts, I am trying to calculate the percentage of values from each dict, sum_allBlocks and sum_allBounds. I then add this data to a new dict as a list.

Can someone help me to avoid my ZeroDivideError that I get whenever one of the values in sum_allBounds is zero? Got a syntax error when adding the try: except: inside the for loop.

```
#Get Block% by Stand from allstands, add to daily_details as percent_allBlocks

def get_flight_details(stand_data):
    for _key, allstands in stand_data.items():
        daily_details = {}
        divide_allBlocks = ["{0:3.1f}%".format(a / b * 100) for a, b in zip(sum_allBlocks, sum_allBounds)]
        daily_details['percent_allBlocks'] = divide_allBlocks
```

Comment: What do you want to do when `b` is zero in the list comprehension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not pretty but you can do that.

```
def get_flight_details(stand_data):
    for _key, allstands in stand_data.items():
        daily_details = {}
        divide_allBlocks = ["{0:3.1f}%".format(a/b*100 if b!=0 else <PUT A DEFAULT VALUE HERE>) for a, b in zip(sum_allBlocks, sum_allBounds)]
        daily_details['percent_allBlocks'] = divide_allBlocks
```

Comment: it would be prettier if you split the comprehension over multiple lines

Comment: @JustinWood glad it helped! 
Chris_Rands: true, I just wanted to provide a solution that *looked* like the initial code.

Answer (score 0):

I have this and it seems also to work.

```
try:
    divide_allBlocks = ["{0:3.1f}%".format(a / b * 100) for a, b in zip(sum_allBlocks, sum_allBounds)]
except ZeroDivisionError:
    divide_allBlocks = [0.0 for a, b in zip(sum_allBlocks, sum_allBounds)]
daily_details['percent_allBlocks'] = divide_allBlocks
```